# Group By column, returning most recent AND earliest fields

Tags: mysql, group-by, timestamp

I have a table:

```
ITEM    NOTE        RECORD_DATE             USER
Apple   Blah        2016-12-30 11:22:33     mcmurphy510
Orange  Somenote    2016-12-31 11:22:33     user2
Apple   BlahBlah    2017-01-01 11:22:33     user2
```

I'm trying to create a query that will show the Item, and most recent Note.  I also need to derrive four fields from the DATE and USER columns:

`CREATED`:  should be the `RECORD_DATE` timestamp of the *earliest* row for given `ITEM`

`CREATED_BY`:  should be the `USER` of the *earliest* row for given `ITEM`

`UPDATED`:  should be the `RECORD_DATE` timestamp of the *most recent* row for given `ITEM`

`UPDATED_BY`:  should be the `USER` of the *most recent* row for given `ITEM`

I've managed to get one or the other (either earliest or latest), but not both, using the following query:

```
SELECT
    i.item,
    i.note,
    i.record_date AS created,
    i.user AS created_by
FROM
    item i
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            item,
            MAX(record_date) as record_date
        FROM item
        GROUP BY item
    ) i2
        ON (
            i.item = i2.item AND
            i.record_date = i2.record_date
        )
```

Using this, I can switch between returning the earliest and most recent `RECORD_DATE` by switching between `MAX()` and `MIN()` in the sub query.

My question is how can I create a signle query that can show both the earliest AND most recent results in the same row?

**Desired Result:**

```
ITEM    NOTE        CREATED                 CREATED_BY      UPDATED                 UPDATED_BY
Apple   BlahBlah    2016-12-30 11:22:33     mcmurphy510     2017-01-01 11:22:33     user2
Orange  Somenote    2016-12-31 11:22:33     user2           NULL                    NULL
```

I have a fiddle up here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd724a/3

Comment: Why wouldn't the Orange row appear twice? It *is* both after all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find earliest and latest date for each item and then join with the main table like this:

```
select
    i1.item,
    i2.note,
    i1.record_date created_date,
    i1.user create_user,
    case when i1.record_date <> i2.record_date then i2.record_date end update_date,
    case when i1.record_date <> i2.record_date then i2.user end update_user
from item i1
inner join item i2
on i1.item = i2.item
inner join (
select item, min(record_date) mn, max(record_date) mx
from item
group by item
) i3 on i1.item = i3.item
and i1.record_date = i3.mn
and i2.record_date = i3.mx;
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd724a/4)

Comment: This works well, but it looks like it's returning the first (earliest) `note` for each item.  I'm trying to have `note` always be the most recent.

Comment: Updated. You just needed to change i1 to i2

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate first and last at once and use them both in the join criteria, like so:

```
SELECT i.item, i.note, i.record_date AS created, i.user AS created_by
FROM item i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT item
        , MAX(record_date) as lastDate
        , MIN(record_date) as firstDate
    FROM item
    GROUP BY item
) AS flDates
ON i.item = flDates.item 
   AND i.record_date IN (flDates.firstDate, flDates.lastDate)
```

or, you might get a faster query by using a UNION on the subquery and avoid the index-wasting `OR` implied by the above's `IN` condition, like so:

```
SELECT i.item, i.note, i.record_date AS created, i.user AS created_by
FROM item i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT item, MIN(record_date) as record_date
    FROM item
    GROUP BY item
    UNION
    SELECT item, MAX(record_date) as record_date
    FROM item
    GROUP BY item
) AS flDates
ON i.item = flDates.item AND i.record_date = flDates.record_date
```

If the table has an index on `(item, record_date)`, it is more likely to be faster than the first version; but without such an index the separate calculation of `MIN` and `MAX` values could end up taking longer.